# Can we set global "consumes" and "produces" in OpenAPI/Swagger 2.0?

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-2.0

In the each path I need to set `consumes` and `produces`. Can I set them globally?

```
post:
      summary: ""
      description: ""
      consumes:
      - "application/json"
      - "application/xml"
      produces:
      - "application/xml"
      - "application/json"
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sure. You can specify `consumes` and `produces` on the root level of the spec, and they will be inherited by all operations. Global `consumes` and `produces` can be overridden on the operation level if needed.

```yaml
swagger: '2.0'
...

consumes:
  - application/json
  - application/xml
produces:
  - application/xml
  - application/json

paths:
  /foo:
    get:
      # This inherits global `produces`
      ...

    post:
      # Here we override global `consumes`
      consumes:
        - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
      ...
```

More info: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/mime-types/

Comment: You save me time