# In OpenAPI 3, how to document that an Accept header with a specified value is necessary on request in order for a successful API call?

Tags: openapi

For a legacy API that I document in order for a successful authentication I need to provide the following headers:

```
X-Access-Token: {token}
Accept: application/json; version=public/v2
```

For the token part I need document it via:

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  version: "v2"
  title: Company App Public Api
  description: Integrate your platform with company app website

components:
  securitySchemes:
    ApiKey:
      type: 'apiKey'
      in: 'header'
      name: 'X-Access-Token'
security:
  - ApiKey: []
```

But how I can document that also for an authentication I need to provide an `Accept: application/json; version=public/v2`. The `Accept` header must contain the `application/json; version=public/v2` anything else returns `406 Not Acceptable` header.

Also, the header `Accept` with value `application/json; version=public/v2` should be in my request. The response header is always `application/json`.

Do you know how I can document that?

Comment: Related (or duplicate): [How to set the Accept header globally in OpenAPI 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54145884/113116)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In OpenAPI 3.0, the *request* header `Accept` and the *response* header `Content-Type` are both defined as `responses.<code>.content.<Accept value>`. This needs to be defined in every operation.

```yaml
paths:
  /something:
    get:
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Successful operation
          content:
            'application/json; version=public/v2':  # <-----
              schema:
                ...
         '406':
           description: Invalid media type was specified in the `Accept` header (should be `application/json; version=public/v2`)
```

Comment: But the `Accept` header with `application/json; version=public/v2` should be in my request's `Accept` header.

Comment: `responses.<code>.content.<media-type>` defines both the request `Accept` header and the response `Content-Type`.

Comment: But in my api the Request needs different value from the response

Answer (score 3):

In order to specify that you should perform a http request using the `application/json; version=public/v2` accept header you should document it like this:

```
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  version: "v2"
  title: Company App Public Api
  description: Integrate your platform with company app website

components:
  securitySchemes:
    ApiKey:
      type: 'apiKey'
      in: 'header'
      name: 'X-Access-Token'
   
  responses:
    406:
      description: "Is returned once `Accept` header has not been provided or does not contain the `application/json; version=public/v2` value."
      content:
        'application/json':
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              error:
                type: 'boolean'
              type:
                type: 'string'
              message:
                type: 'string'
                description: "Your access token is either missing or incorrect. Please check the X-Access-Token header and try again."
    401:
      description: "Is returned once `X-Access-Token` has not been provided"
      content:
        'application/json':
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              error:
                type: 'boolean'
              type:
                type: 'string'
              message:
                description: "Your access token is either missing or incorrect. Please check the X-Access-Token header and try again."
security:
  - ApiKey: []  

paths:
   /myendpoint:
     put:
       requestBody:
         required: true
         content: 
           'application/json; version=public/v2': {}
         
       responses:
         200:
            'application/json':
               #your response jhere as documented in
         406:
           $ref: '#/components/responses/406'
         401:
           $ref: '#/components/responses/401'
```

So with this approach you tell in the documentation that the request should be a `put` one with the `Accept` header `application/json; version=public/v2` with any (or no) parameters.

Though for `get` requests `requestBody` is not a valid definition.